# Update a column values for a subset of rows in DT1 based on DT2 column values

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following two data.tables

```
library(data.table)
DT1 = data.table(x=LETTERS[1:9], y=c(15:18,NA,20,NA, NA, 23) , v=1:9)
DT2 = data.table(x=LETTERS[1:9], y=99:107, v=19:27)
```

While joining the tables on x, how can I update the values of DT1$y to match the values of DT2$y only for the rows where Column y is NA in DT1.

The final result would be:

```
   x  y  v
1: A 15  1
2: B 16  2
3: C 17  3
4: D 18  4
5: E 103 5
6: F 20  6
7: G 105 7
8: H 106 8
9: I 23  9
```

I know I could do the following to update the entire column y in DT1, but not sure how to limit the Column y update only to NA values.

```
DT[DT2, y:=i.y, on="x"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an "update join":

```
DT1[is.na(y), y := DT2[.SD, on=.(x), x.y]]
```

*How it works*

The data.table syntax is `x[i, j]` and can be read as...

1. subset by `i`; then
2. do `j`.

Other notes:

- Inside `j`, `.SD` refers to the subsetted table.
- Inside `j` of `x[i, on=, j]`, the `x.*` prefix indicates that the column is taken from `x`.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I could use your solution to update two columns (x and y) instead of just one column y?  Thanks!

Comment: @user6340762 If I understand your case correctly, I'd do something like `DT1[is.na(y), c("x", "y") := DT2[.SD, on=.(g), .(x.x, x.y)]]`